# What is a “SKL i7-Entry (AMD Exo XT 4GB)” processor?

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7

Did anyone ever come across this processor: **SKL i7-Entry (AMD Exo XT 4GB)**?

I found it in a dell config: http://www.dell.com/fr/entreprise/p/inspiron-17-5759-laptop/pd?oc=bn75903&model_id=inspiron-17-5759-laptop

In the page whith less details, they say it's an Intel Core i7 processor but in this page with more details, it's different, and no other indication is provided. Even a google search didn't provide me with any information. And the dell support chat person didn't know about it neither.

Comment: I suspect Its lost in translation. It only seems to be listed on european dell sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKL i7 = Skylake i7, Intel's 6th generation i7 processor.

I assume the AMD ... refers to the video card?